# Program using ceil()

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, ceil

I did the following code using ceil()

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>    
int main()
{
  float val;
  float cVal;

  val=23.4;

  cVal =ceil(val);
  printf("ceil value:%f\n",cVal);
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting th following error
In function `main':
test1.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to`ceil'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What is wrong in this code??Please help!

I asked this code before but then I did not specify how I compiled this program. A person suggested to include -lm while compiling when using gcc. But,

I compiled it using makefile

```
>>cmake .
>>make
>>./hello.out
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to link your executable with the math library.

For example:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello -lm
```

Answer (score 1):

Most mathematical functions live in their own library that needs to be linked with the main program. This library is aptly called `m`.

So you need to add a [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/target_link_libraries.html) to your `CMakeLists.txt` file to include the `m` library.